# p5.js - Low FPS for some basic animations

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm having really bad performance on a project i wrote in Javascript (with the p5.js library)

Here is the code:

```
const fps = 60;
const _width = 400;
const _height = 300;
const firePixelChance = 1;
const coolingRate = 1;
const heatSourceSize = 10;
const noiseIncrement = 0.02;
const fireColor = [255, 100, 0, 255];

const bufferWidth = _width;
const bufferHeight = _height;

let buffer1;
let buffer2;
let coolingBuffer;

let ystart = 0.0;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(_width, _height);
    frameRate(fps);

    buffer1 = createGraphics(bufferWidth, bufferHeight);
    buffer2 = createGraphics(bufferWidth, bufferHeight);
    coolingBuffer = createGraphics(bufferWidth, bufferHeight);
}

// Draw a line at the bottom
function heatSource(buffer, rows, _color) {
    const start = bufferHeight - rows;
    for (let x = 0; x < bufferWidth; x++) {
        for (let y = start; y < bufferHeight; y++) {
            if(Math.random() >= firePixelChance)
                continue;

            buffer.pixels[(x + (y * bufferWidth)) * 4] = _color[0];    // Red
            buffer.pixels[(x + (y * bufferWidth)) * 4 +1] = _color[1]; // Green
            buffer.pixels[(x + (y * bufferWidth)) * 4 +2] = _color[2]; // Blue
            buffer.pixels[(x + (y * bufferWidth)) * 4 +3] = 255;       // Alpha
        }
    }
}

// Produces the 'smoke'
function coolingMap(buffer){
    let xoff = 0.0;
    for(x = 0; x < bufferWidth; x++){
        xoff += noiseIncrement;
        yoff = ystart;
        for(y = 0; y < bufferHeight; y++){
            yoff += noiseIncrement;
            n = noise(xoff, yoff);
            bright = pow(n, 3) * 20;
            buffer.pixels[(x + (y * bufferWidth)) * 4] = bright;
            buffer.pixels[(x + (y * bufferWidth)) * 4 +1] = bright;
            buffer.pixels[(x + (y * bufferWidth)) * 4 +2] = bright;
            buffer.pixels[(x + (y * bufferWidth)) * 4 +3] = bright;
        }
    }

    ystart += noiseIncrement;
}

// Change color of a pixel so it looks like its smooth
function smoothing(buffer, _buffer2, _coolingBuffer) {
    for (let x = 0; x < bufferWidth; x++) {
        for (let y = 0; y < bufferHeight; y++) {
            // Get all 4 neighbouring pixels
            const left = getColorFromPixelPosition(x+1,y,buffer.pixels);
            const right = getColorFromPixelPosition(x-1,y,buffer.pixels);
            const bottom = getColorFromPixelPosition(x,y+1,buffer.pixels);
            const top = getColorFromPixelPosition(x,y-1,buffer.pixels);

            // Set this pixel to the average of those neighbours
            let sumRed = left[0] + right[0] + bottom[0] + top[0];
            let sumGreen = left[1] + right[1] + bottom[1] + top[1];
            let sumBlue = left[2] + right[2] + bottom[2] + top[2];
            let sumAlpha = left[3] + right[3] + bottom[3] + top[3];

            // "Cool down" color
            const coolingMapColor = getColorFromPixelPosition(x,y,_coolingBuffer.pixels)
            sumRed = (sumRed / 4) - (Math.random() * coolingRate) - coolingMapColor[0];
            sumGreen = (sumGreen / 4) - (Math.random() * coolingRate) - coolingMapColor[1];
            sumBlue = (sumBlue / 4) - (Math.random() * coolingRate) - coolingMapColor[2];
            sumAlpha = (sumAlpha / 4) - (Math.random() * coolingRate) - coolingMapColor[3];

            // Make sure we dont get negative numbers
            sumRed = sumRed > 0 ? sumRed : 0;
            sumGreen = sumGreen > 0 ? sumGreen : 0;
            sumBlue = sumBlue > 0 ? sumBlue : 0;
            sumAlpha = sumAlpha > 0 ? sumAlpha : 0;

            // Update this pixel
            _buffer2.pixels[(x + ((y-1) * bufferWidth)) * 4] = sumRed;         // Red
            _buffer2.pixels[(x + ((y-1) * bufferWidth)) * 4 +1] = sumGreen;    // Green
            _buffer2.pixels[(x + ((y-1) * bufferWidth)) * 4 +2] = sumBlue;     // Blue
            _buffer2.pixels[(x + ((y-1) * bufferWidth)) * 4 +3] = sumAlpha;    // Alpha
        }
    }
}

function draw() {
    background(0);
    text("FPS: "+Math.floor(frameRate()), 10, 20);
    fill(0,255,0,255);

    buffer1.loadPixels();
    buffer2.loadPixels();
    coolingBuffer.loadPixels();

    heatSource(buffer1, heatSourceSize, fireColor);
    coolingMap(coolingBuffer);
    smoothing(buffer1, buffer2, coolingBuffer);

    buffer1.updatePixels();
    buffer2.updatePixels();
    coolingBuffer.updatePixels();

    let temp = buffer1;
    buffer1 = buffer2;
    buffer2 = temp;

    image(buffer2, 0, 0); // Draw buffer to screen
    // image(coolingBuffer, 0, bufferHeight); // Draw buffer to screen
}

function mousePressed() {
    buffer1.fill(fireColor);
    buffer1.noStroke();
    buffer1.ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 100, 100); 
}

function getColorFromPixelPosition(x, y, pixels) {
    let _color = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        _color[i] = pixels[(x + (y * bufferWidth)) * 4 + i];
    return _color;
}

function getRandomColorValue() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
}
```

I'm getting ~12 FPS on chrome and ~1 FPS on any other browser and i cant figure out why..

Resizing my canvas to make it bigger also impacts the fps negatively...
In the devtools performance tab i noticed that both my `smoothing` and `coolingMap` functions are the things slowing it down, but i cant figure out what part of them are so heavy..

Comment: Well, you're calling those functions on every single pixel on your canvas, so the larger the canvas the slower it's going to be. According to the profiler, most of the processing time in `smoothing` is spent in `p5.noise`. If you can cache your smoke rows and move them up, instead of re-calculating each time, that should save some speed. But I think your main problem is you're doing per-pixel particle systems in JS. Look into using WebGL, perhaps?

Comment: The rising smoke effect looks very cool, though, for what it's worth.

Comment: @WesLord, I tried using the WebGL renderer with the stuff i have now, but i got the same performance.. and the quality was even worse..
I thought i might have done something stupid to get this performance, but i'm starting to think this is normal and i should work on caching stuff and maybe use pixel groups instead of single pixels.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You've pretty much answered this for yourself already:

> i'm starting to think this is normal and i should work on caching stuff and maybe use pixel groups instead of single pixels

Like you're discovering, doing some calculation for every single pixel is pretty slow. Computers only have finite resources, and there's going to be a limit to what you can throw at them.

In your case, you might consider drawing the whole thing to a canvas once at startup, and then moving the canvas up over the life of the program.